# JSON Getting path not using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

i have a txt file named simpleJson.txt

```
{"Dev":[
             {"firstName":"Ivy","lastName":"Razonales", "middleName":"Andres" },
             {"firstName":"Alexis","lastName":"Escober", "middleName":"Johnson" },
             {"firstName":"Dennis John","lastName":"Biel", "middleName":"Smith" }]
}
```

and here is my function

```
function jsoninTxt_func(){

    var obj = JSON.parse("simpleJson.txt");
    var txt = "";
    for (i = 0; i < obj.Dev.length; i++) {
        txt = txt + obj.Dev[i].firstName + " "
                + obj.Dev[i].middleName + " "
                + obj.Dev[i].lastName + "<br>"
    }
    document.getElementById("jsoninTxt").innerHTML = txt;

}
```

I need help how to fix this without using AJAX or JQUERY just the json itself
***var obj = JSON.parse("simpleJson.txt");***

Comment: What is the error which you are getting?

Comment: You'd need to load the contents of that file as a string variable and then you can use [`JSON.parse`](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/json/parse)

Answer (score 0):

**Without using AJAX or JQUERY** means you have to hard-code the JSON in your function as follows -- **no longer in a file**:

```
function jsoninTxt_func(){
    var obj = {"Dev":[
        {"firstName":"Ivy","lastName":"Razonales", "middleName":"Andres" },
        {"firstName":"Alexis","lastName":"Escober", "middleName":"Johnson" },
        {"firstName":"Dennis John","lastName":"Biel", "middleName":"Smith" }]
              };
    var txt = "";
    for (i = 0; i < obj.Dev.length; i++) {
        txt = txt + obj.Dev[i].firstName + " "
        + obj.Dev[i].middleName + " "
        + obj.Dev[i].lastName + "<br>"
    }
    document.getElementById("jsoninTxt").innerHTML = txt;        
}

jsoninTxt_func();
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/B9ME6/)

Comment: Yes there is, ***using jQuery and AJAX***.